# Como puedo tener dos paginas de nodejs en el mismo server con un dominio cada uno?

Tags: nodejs, dominio, ip

Como puedo tener dos paginas de nodejs en el mismo server con un dominio cada uno?

He estado investigando y he visto este codigo:

```
var app = server()
app.listen('http://example.com/')
```

Esto funcionaria con este codigo?:

APP 1

```
var app = server()
app.listen('http://dominio1.com/')
```

APP 2

```
var app = server()
app.listen('http://dominio2.com/')
```

Estos domnios apuntarían a la misma IP.
Entonces si voy a dominio1 saldra el contenido de la app1 y si voy a dominio2 saldra el contenido de la app2 ?

Comment: Usualmente, los servidores de NodeJS se acceden desde un [Proxy Inverso](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_inverso), siendo los más comunes Apache y nginx. Son éstos servidores los que manejan el tema de redirección y dominios. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, como se haría eso por ejemplo con apache? De verdad muchas gracias.

Comment: Hacerlo con Apache dependerá mucho de tu configuración. Te sugiero buscar ejemplos de configuraciones de host virtual y proxy Inverso, no es algo para responder por acá.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias